# How to add days correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to add days to somedays by clicking calendar like tables.

first, I can get endday by clicking,and then,I would like to add days 120 to it.

```
<td id="207" data-class-index="0" data-day="2018/5/21">21</td>
```

my code is like below

```
endday=new Date($(this).data('day'))

console.log("enddate",endday);        

upperlimit=endday.setDate(endday.getDate()+120);

console.log("upperlimit",upperlimit);
```

When I tried to add days, it seems return current time. like this

```
enddate Thu Sep 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
upperlimit Fri Dec 20 2019 11:49:34 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
```

I wonder why this issue incurred, if someone has some experience like this,please let me know how to fix.

Thanks

Comment: When I log `upperLimit` it logs a number, not a date. `setDate()` doesn't return a Date, it returns a timestamp in milliseconds. You should log `endday` at the end to see it in date format.

Comment: The code you posted is not the code that produces that output, and I can't reproduce the problem when I fix the obvious problems. You need to post the actual code.

Comment: although you will answer but I highly recommend if you want to manipulate and change dates, use moment.js and get rid of the headache of Dates in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar stated, `upperlimit` is returning the date in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).. Wrapping that call in `new Date(...)` should resolve it..

```js
$("#btn").on('click', () => {
  let endday = new Date($("#207").data("day"));  
  let upperlimit = new Date(endday.setDate(endday.getDate()+120));
  // Have to add +1 to .getMonth() because JS handles months as 0-11 not 1-12
  let resultHtml = `${upperlimit.getFullYear()}/${upperlimit.getMonth() + 1}/${upperlimit.getDate()}`
  $("#result").html(resultHtml);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="207" data-class-index="0" data-day="2018/5/21">2018/5/21</p>
<button id="btn">Click to add 120 days</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be changing the date of `endday` by calling `setDate` on it. Instead, you should declare `upperlimit` as a new Date first and then set it directly.

```js
const endDay = new Date('Thu Sep 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0900');

console.log("endDay", endDay);

var upperLimit = new Date(endDay);
upperLimit.setDate(endDay.getDate() + 120);

console.log("upperLimit", upperLimit);
```

Comment: Maybe he's OK with updating `endday` in place.

Comment: Sure, then we wouldn't need a second variable. Just `endDay.setDate(endDay.getDate() + 120);` It's assigning to the return value of `setDate` that is causing an issue.

Comment: But it's not causing the issue he posted, because it will set `upperlimit` to the millisecond timestamp of the updated `enddate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(2));
```